# xtragrid Cell and rows Selection Using Devexpress Winforms Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As 
    RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellStyle
    Try
        If IsDBNull(e.CellValue) Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
        End If
        Dim selectedCells As GridCell() = GridView1.GetSelectedCells()
        isRowSelected = GridView1.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle)
        For Each Cells In selectedCells
            If GridView1.GetSelectedCells.Count = 1 Then
                If IsDBNull(GridView1.GetRowCellValue(Cells.RowHandle, 
                    Cells.Column)) Then
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                End If
            Else
                If isRowSelected Then
                    If IsDBNull(GridView1.GetRowCellValue(Cells.RowHandle, 
                        Cells.Column)) Then
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 234, 
                            253)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image: This is my Output Screen Devexpress xtragrid]

I am using DevExpress .i declare the 'DbNull' value should be Default Color in 'Lightyellow'.After i want to be selected the rows or Cell in 'DbNull' value to change the Blue Color. What did I do wrong?
I Want to be Select the Cells or Rows to be change the color(that null value also)

Comment: What should change to blue? The whole row, or just that cell?

Comment: selected row or cell to be change Blue color.(That Null Value also)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to iterate through the selected cells in the RowCellStyle event handler since this event is raised only for a single cell. Eventually, it will raise for all visible cells.

Thus, the following code will be enough to complete your task:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RowCellStyleEventArgs)
    Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim isRowSelected As Boolean = view.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle)
    If IsDbNull(e.CellValue) AndAlso (Not isRowSelected) Then
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
End Sub
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: No.i selected particular HireDate Column Cell but nearly null cell value also change the Yellow color.but i need only selected null value to be change the color blue color.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim state As GridRowCellState
        state = DirectCast(e.Cell, GridCellInfo).State
        If (state And GridRowCellState.Selected) = GridRowCellState.Selected Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 234, 253)
        End If
```

This Code Used for Selecting Cells to be Change your Appearance Color.
GridRowCellState is Contains row cell states for the Grid Control's appearance customization events.Selected Cells is Specifies that the row/cell being currently processed is selected.
[This is My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMlf4.jpg)

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Can you add detail explaining your answer?

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.